# Cant get PHP PDO to send to DB

Tags: php, pdo

I can't get this code to set the input in form to my database, and I can't figure out why. Is there any that can help me figure you why?

I'm trying to use the form to get input from user.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Etternavn:<br>
    <input type="text" name="etternavn" id="etternavn" placeholder="Etternavn"><br>
    Fornavn:<br>
    <input type="text" name="fornavn" id="fornavn" placeholder="Fornavn"><br>
    Klasse:<br>
    <input type="text" name="klasse" id="klasse" placeholder="Klasse"><br>
    Mobil:<br>
    <input type="text" name="mobli" id="mobil" placeholder="Mobil"><br>
    Nettside:<br>
    <input type="text" name="www" id="www" placeholder="Nettside"><br>
    Epost:<br>
    <input type="email" name="epost" id="epost" placeholder="Epost">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here I'm running the PHP PDO to get hold in the database and try to put the user input in to the database but I can't see why it doesn't work. I don't get any messages that tell me that anything is wrong.

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $host = "kark.hin.no";
    $dbname = "stud_v16_klemetsen";
    $username = "v16_klemetsen";
    $password = "**********";

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $q = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO studenter(etternavn,fornavn,klasse,mobil,www,epost)
        VALUES (:etternavn, :fornavn, :klasse, :mobil, :www, :epost");
        $q->bindParam(':etternavn',$_POST['etternavn'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->bindParam(':fornavn',$_POST['fornavn'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->bindParam(':klasse',$_POST['klasse'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->bindParam(':mobil',$_POST['mobil'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->bindParam(':adr',$_POST['www'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->bindParam(':epost',$_POST['epost'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->execute();

        $q->execute();
        echo "succssfull";

    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        echo "ERROR" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $dbh = null;
}
?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: the error is that nothing happens,i dont get any message that say anything is wrong and it dont put any to my database..

Comment: Is the HTML and PHP code on the same page?

Comment: yes im using the HTML and PHP on same page,thats why i dont have set any action in form

Answer (score 1):

`$q->bindParam(':adr',$_POST['www'],PDO::PARAM_STR);`

This line does not match with your SQL

`"INSERT INTO studenter(etternavn,fornavn,klasse,mobil,www,epost)
  VALUES (:etternavn, :fornavn, :klasse, :mobil, :www, :epost"`

Your bind parameter must be `:www`

Comment: even if i do thise changes i dont get anything added to my database sadly

Comment: Yes, sorry I just saw something else.
Your SQL Syntax isn't correct, you forgot a `)` :
`INSERT INTO studenter(etternavn,fornavn,klasse,mobil,www,epost)
 VALUES (:etternavn, :fornavn, :klasse, :mobil, :www, :epost)`

Answer (score -1):

Also, you're missing an end closing bracket `)` in your SQL query, it should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO studenter(etternavn,fornavn,klasse,mobil,www,epost)
        VALUES (:etternavn, :fornavn, :klasse, :mobil, :www, :epost)";
$q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: In fact, you must not.

Comment: hey that wasn't nice, I worked my poor finger typing all that lol @YourCommonSense x)

Comment: even if i do thise changes i dont get anything added to my database sadly

Comment: turn on error reporting and post your error: `error_reporting(1);`

Comment: i dont get any errors.the only thing i have is when i hold my mouse over:  $q = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO studenter(etternavn,fornavn,klasse,mobil,www,epost)
        VALUES (:etternavn, :fornavn, :klasse, :mobil, :www, :epost)"); i get get this:No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance

Comment: Turn on the `error_reporting` and then rerun the program.

Comment: i have implemeted error_reporting(E_ALL) after $dbh = null; and after echo "succssfull" and i dont get anything from it

Comment: Put it at the top of the page :)

Comment: i still dont get any error message